# Определение размерности входящего массива (Java)

Tags: java, массивы

```
public static void createField(char cell[][])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            cell[i][j] = '|';
        }
    }
}
```

На вход приходит двумерный массив. Как его заполнять в зависимости от количества строк и столбцов?

Например массив 4 х 4 — заполнится, а вот если поменять значение на 5 х 3, то нет. Пробовал типа `i < cell[i].length` и `j < cell[j].length` — кидает `Exception`.

Comment: У вас в length опечатка или вы так и писали в коде?

Comment: в коде я нормально писал это по памяти так напечатал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void createField(char cell[][])
{
   for (int i = 0; i < cell.length; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < cell[i].length; j++)
      {
         cell[i][j] = '|';
      }
   }
}
```

---

Для лучшего понимания абстрагируемся одним из способов (любым более удобным для вас):

1. На самом деле вам ведь нужно обойти массив `cell`(лучше представьте
   себе его одномерным массивом, а не двумерным), каждым элементом
   которого является еще один массив. Таким образом, обратившись к полю
   `cell.lenght` мы получаем размер массива `cell` (количество
   элементов в нем), а затем для каждого его элемента (который является
   вложенным массивом), мы узнаем его длину посредством
   `cell[i].lenght`, затем же посредством индексов `i` и `j` мы
   обращаемся к `i`-му элементу массива `cell`, и к `j`-му элементу
   вложенного массива в `i`-ую ячейку массива `cell`.
2. Представьте себе его как матрицу `n x m` (на самом деле это не так, т.к. в матрице количество столбцов в каждой строке обязано быть одинаковым, а здесь нет). Касательно нашего примера: мы узнаем количество строк в матрице, а затем для каждой строки количество столбцов в ней, а затем обращаемся к `i`-ой строке и `j`-му столбцу и заполняем элемент по этому адресу.

Comment: Попробовал как вы написали выкинуло"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4"

Comment: @spingalet Вы точно уверены в этом? Могу привести более развернутый код с объяснениями, но мне кажется, что так довольно лаконично и сразу понятно, что именно делалось не так :)

Comment: прошу прощения , не всмотрелся что во вложенном цикле "i" , а не "j".Все работает.Спасибо вам за помощь

Comment: Сам буду разбиратся) так лучше пойму . Спасибо

Comment: @spingalet Да не за что, но я, все-таки, тогда поясню (подправлю сам ответ) вы можете сразу не читать, если очень хотите :)

Comment: очень хорошо обяснили, все понял спасибо Вам большое)